# How to get relative URLs with url() in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have done searches and cannot find anything that solves this in Laravel 5.2.

Is it possible to generate relative URLs in Laravel 5.2?

Meaning, instead of `http://example.com/mypage` I get simply `/mypage` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should use [`$request->path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#basic-request-information), it will return the `URI`.

Answer (score 43):

If you are trying to *generate* them, rather than retrieve the current one, you can pass a 3rd parameter to the `route` function.

```php
echo route('about', [], false);
```

If you pass `true` (the default) as the 3rd parameter it will give you

http://example.com/about

If you pass `false` as the 3rd parameter it will give you

/about

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: @AmitShah agreed