# diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs, is there a way to change the parent to custom links?

Tags: php, laravel, breadcrumbs

i used some breadcrumbs that look like this

```
Breadcrumbs::for('blog', function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) {
    $trail->parent('home');
    $trail->push('Blog', route('blog'));
});
```

it work but my app is in *somewebsite.com/myapp/*

I want to make the parent go to */myapp/* instead of *somewebsite.com*

is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project maintainer here, guessing you've solved this by now but figured I'd reply all the same.

Breadcrumbs is simply ingesting the output of Laravel's `route('blog')` function, which, by default, is an absolute URL. [You *should* be able to pass `false` as a third parameter to get the output you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45171764/2535504)

```
$trail->push('Blog', route('blog', [], false));
```